# Why does variable containing "c" not equal "c" in my while loop? Trying to break when an input matches

Tags: python, while-loop, count, infinite-loop

I'm trying to implement a scoring system using counts that are initiated prior to this code. However, I want to keep checking the input until the user enters the correct winner. If they enter Adam, Bill or Draw the first time, the program skips my while loop. However, if they enter an option not here, like "Caroline", I get stuck in an endless loop in the while loop (even if I enter the correct answer once we enter the while loop).

Once I enter the while loop because of an initial failure, even if I type "adam", I receive the print error and I'm not sure why, since gameLower should == "adam". What am I missing?

```
game = input("Who won, Adam or Bill, or a draw (enter D for draw): ")
gameLower = game.lower()
print(gameLower)

while gameLower != "adam" or gameLower != "bill" or gameLower != "d":
    print("Sorry, I didn't understand who the winner was. Adam, Bill or a draw (D)?")
    game = input("Who won, Adam or Bill, or a draw (enter D for draw): ")
    gameLower = game.lower()
else:
    break
```

Comment: Think about the condition you're looping on. If `gameLower == 'adam'`, `gameLower != 'bill'` and it's still true overall.

Comment: Oh. My mistake. Thank you! Can't believe that was my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop condition is a tautology, an expression whose truth value is always `true` regardless of its variables' values. You need to use `and` instead of `or`.

```
gameLower value| != "adam" | != "bill" | != "d" | OR'ed | AND'ed
---------------+-----------+-----------+--------+-------+-------
"adam"         |  false    | true      | true   | true  | false
"bill"         |  true     | false     | true   | true  | false
"d"            |  true     | true      | false  | true  | false
"other value"  |  true     | true      | true   | true  | true
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry. Silly question. Didn't realise my trivial error.

Comment: Happens to the best of us :)

Comment: @Karim By the way, a better (shorter, clearer) way to express this is `some_string.lower() in ["adam", "bill", "d"]`

Comment: Clever! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

my friend.
At first you need to use AND instead of OR in your while conditions but generally, you have to use another way like what I want to tell you to know:
Because you want to check user’s answer over and over until he inputs a right parameter so you have to use an endless WHILE (ex: WHILE(1) ) and in your while, you have to use an IF and an ELSE condition! In your IF you have to use this condition(that you have in your WHILE now) with AND! And at the end of your IF you have to use CONTINUE and at end of your ELSE you have to use BREAK for jump out from your WHILE! If you need more help tell me to write it for you and send if here.